# Task.StartNew holds the main thread while running

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

While this code is running i cant move or do anything in my UI:

```
var a = txtLot.Text;
var b = cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString();
var c = cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString();

var itm = Task<JDEItemLotAvailability>
.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Red;
        var ret = Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c);
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        return ret;
}
    );
lblDescriptionValue.Text = itm.Result.Description;
lblItemCodeValue.Text = itm.Result.Code;
lblQuantityValue.Text = itm.Result.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
```

I tried commenting on the call to the Dal method and putting thread.sleep(5000) instead but i still could'nt move the form.

edit: maybe i am using the wrong way to get back the result?

**UPDATE:**

After the first reply (John's) i tried this:

```
var a = txtLot.Text;
var b = cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString();
var c = cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString();

var itm = Task<JDEItemLotAvailability>
.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Red;
        var ret = Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c);
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        return ret;
}
    ).ContinueWith(itm =>
{
lblDescriptionValue.Text = itm.Result.Description;
lblItemCodeValue.Text = itm.Result.Code;
lblQuantityValue.Text = itm.Result.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
});
```

but of course i am messing ui again....The form freezing went away, but when task finished the exception occured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, your code is trying to access the UI thread from what is almost certainly a different thread (i.e. within the task, which will probably be executing in a thread-pool thread). You shouldn't do that.

Secondly, you're blocking the UI thread here:

```
lblDescriptionValue.Text = itm.Result.Description;
```

Access to the `itm.Result` property will *block* until the task has completed. You don't want to do that - this time *in* the UI thread - as that will freeze your UI, as you've observed.

If you're using C# 5 and .NET 4.5, you could try to use the new asynchrony features - that's likely to make it *much* easier to do what you want.

If you can't use .NET 4.5 (or the asynchrony targeting pack for .NET 4) you should use `Task.ContinueWith` to tell the `Task` what you want to do when it's completed.

EDIT: I suspect you want something like:

```
var a = txtLot.Text;
var b = cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString();
var c = cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString();

btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Red;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c));
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    lblDescriptionValue.Text = t.Result.Description;
    lblItemCodeValue.Text = t.Result.Code;
    lblQuantityValue.Text = t.Result.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I see, i cant use 4.5 because i need the apps to run on some XP machines so i will have to stick with Task class. Can you tell me more about how to remove any ui elements from the code and use the continuewith? i tries to use it but i am still getting errors..(i am updating th epost with the second try

Comment: Well, the first thing you do is set the background colour to red - so just do that before starting the task. Then you can set it back to transparent when it's completed. I'll edit with some sample code.

Comment: Thanks, and if you could showcase what i will have to do with ContinueWith (with the result i mean). Thank you!

Comment: @e4rthdog: See my edit. But again, if you could use the .NET 4 async targeting pack, this would be much simpler.

Comment: It worked as expected john. But i tried the same before you wrote it BUT without the  **TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()** and i got the cross thread exception.

Also i just saw the async targeting pack, and i cant understand why something so usefull like this is not in the headlines..Or maybe it is and i am too much of a noob :)

Comment: @e4rthdog: You need to move the changes to `BackColor` out of the task as well, don't forget.

Comment: Yeap it was the first i did after you told me.